# Sparse Neural Networks with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have taken a few deeplearning.ai courses, all of which focus on fully-connected network topologies which are all interconnected while neglecting sparsely connected ones.

I am wondering if I can use Tensorflow to calculate both the forward and backward propagation of a sparse neural network, like the following:

[image: sparse network]

I'm assuming traditional matrix operations won't work for this type of topology, since not all nodes are connected equally.